# Relational Data in Array?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store relational data (integers).
Each integer represents a foreign column:

```
system table:
| id |  c1 |  c2 |  c3 | ... | c15 |
|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 21 | 2.2 | 2.4 | 2.6 |     | 5.0 |
|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|


collections table:
| id | sytemId |   collection   |
|----|---------|----------------|
|  8 |      21 | [1,3,6,4,2]    | // c1,c3,c6,c4,c2
|  9 |      21 | [12,8,10,7,11] | // c12,c8,c10,c7,c11
```

The array items order is important.
There is no need (yet) to search for a collection. When a system object is loaded, all the related entries in the collections table are fetched too and handled in the application (php).

Now I would like to know if this is the appropriate way to implement this,
or should i use a lookup table ? In case this is the way to go, what would be the best datatype for "collection" ? JSON ?

Best regards

Comment: It's simple: If you want to do this, DON'T use an RDBMS.

Comment: If you are using MySQL 5.7.9+ you can use JSON data type, and store it as a JSON Array.

Comment: To be helpful, I'd need a little more background. I don't think I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Also let us know what you already tried and why/where you think you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I would like to know if this is the appropriate way to implement this

No, no, a thousand times no.

> or should i use a lookup table ?

Yes. You need to normalize this data.

Even though MySQL offers ways to store JSON data, if you store these many to one relationships like this you'll defeat most of the benefits of your relational data management system.

Comment: In general yet, but thinking about application needs, performance and scalability for example, This afirmation is not an absolute truth.

Answer (score 0):

An outer-box answer.

Do not think about relational data, rules, models, etc you may focus on your application needs.

JSON Data Types in MySQL can bring more flexibility to RDBMS models, to architecture hybrids models. You could emulate an entire document-oriented NoSQL database in MySQL, but it would [negate many benefits of SQL](https://www.sitepoint.com/sql-vs-nosql-choose/), and you might as well switch to a real NoSQL system. That said, JSON data types could save some effort for more obscure data requirements within an SQL-based application.

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type defined by
> [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) that enables efficient access to data in JSON (JavaScript
> Object Notation) documents. The JSON data type provides these
> advantages over storing JSON-format strings in a string column.

You must take in counting the size what this data could become

> The space required to store a JSON document is roughly the same as for
> LONGBLOB or LONGTEXT;  It is important to keep in mind that the size
> of any JSON document stored in a JSON column is limited to the value
> of the `max_allowed_packet` system variable. (When the server is
> manipulating a JSON value internally in memory, it can be larger than
> this; the limit applies when the server stores it.)

If you need query it, making searching, and use it using DB JSON functions,  you should use a JSON data type.

If you just need to store but never make operations with this information using DB JSON functions, you should not use JSON data type, instead, you can use a simple text field.

If you don't know what will you do with this data yet, do not use JSON format, use a relational and normalized data model. JSON value fields cannot be indexed.

More info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html